# How to create custom non-storage plugin for Apache Drill

Tags: java, apache-drill

How I can create execution plugin for Drill, for example, for automatically running queries for existing data sources? In Drill documented only how to create storage plugins (connectors for data sources).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you're looking for is more along the lines of a query scheduler rather than a plugin for Drill.  Or can you clarify a bit about what you're trying to do.